# SwiftUI View Modifier with the same name for different structs

Tags: swift

I would like to create a `ViewModifier` called `prettify()` which I could use on different structs say `TextField` or `TextEditor`, however I would like to be able to use different rules depending if it's `TextField` or `TextEditor`. So far it's easy. Most importantly I would like to be able to apply this modifier anywhere in modifiers hierarchy.

Say I have

```swift
struct TextFieldModifier: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .padding()
            .background(Color(.systemRed))
    }
}

struct TextEditorModifier: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .padding()
            .background(Color(.systemBlue))
    }
}

extension TextField {
    func prettify() -> some View {
        modifier(TextFieldModifier())
    }
}

extension TextEditor {
    func prettify() -> some View {
        modifier(TextEditorModifier())
    }
}
```

I can now do

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var username = ""
    @State var name = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("username", text: $username)
                .prettify()
            
            TextEditor(text: $name)
                .prettify()
        }
    }
}
```

However, I really wanna be able to do something like

```swift
        VStack {
            TextField("username", text: $username)
                .someModifier()
                .anotherModifier()
                .prettify()
            
            TextEditor(text: $name)
                .anotherModifier()
                .prettify()
        }
```

For this to work I have to introduce something like

```swift
extension View {
    func prettify() -> some View {
      if rootObject == textEditor { ???
        modifier(TextEditorModifier())
      } else {
        modifier(TextFieldModifier())
      }
    }
}
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: Why not make a PrettyTextField and a PrettyTextEditor?

Answer (score 0):

Add this condition

```
extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func prettify() -> some View {
        if self is TextEditor { // <-- Here
            modifier(TextEditorModifier())
        } else {
            modifier(TextFieldModifier())
        }
    }
}
```